# weirdest error on Mac OSx -printf even with

Tags: macos, find, printf, homebrew

Even after installing via brew findutils on mac I keep getting a very very nasty

```
 find: -printf: unknown option"
```

when passing this line on bash

```
"find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.html" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' "
```

what works fine on linux

Can you please please please help in finding and alternative or understand why, even with findutils mac osx is letting me down big time ?
Ta muchly and a lot of love and happiness for whomever replies !!!!

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in `find` binary doesn't support the `-printf` command. This is what you're executing. Try running `type find` and you'll probably see `find is /usr/bin/find`.

I believe your problem here is that `brew install findutils` actually prefixes all of the installed programs with the letter `g`, so what you want is `gfind` instead of `find`.

Comment: this worked thank you :) g find was the way to use the findutils of brew you are a star :D